# Buffer is used, but may not have been initialized (in visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, initialization, buffer

This is a snippet of my `c++` code:

```
char buff[512];
memset(buff, ' ', sizeof(buff));
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buff, _MAX_PATH);
char *file = strrchr(buff, '.');
```

It seems `buff` is initialized in the first line. But I get this from visual studio(This is a warning, not an error, I want to remove this warning):

```
'buff' is not initialized 
'buff' is used, but may not have been initialized
```

What's the problem?

Comment: How did you declare `buff`?

Comment: `It seems buff is initialized in the first line` No it's not. Is `buff` a pointer or array? If it's a pointer, have you allocated space for it - ex. with `new`?

Comment: Initialization happens at the point of declaration.

Comment: Shouldn't you assign `buf` a value before attempting to pass its value to `memset`?

Comment: I declared char buff[512];@user0042

Comment: Use std::vector or std::array in C++.

Comment: See my edit. @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @Patris I just copied and pasted that code into VS2013 and received no such warning - with /Wall.

Comment: This was strange for me, and for this, I asked it here.@JohnnyMopp

Comment: So buff isn't initialised. Its declared, then filled with spaces. Then a function call which can failed is done. Then it is passed into a function which REQUIRES a nul terminated string. Tell me which part of your code guarantees the string is nul terminated?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a plain `char*` pointer for `buff` like this:

```
char* buff;
```

instead of

```
char buff[_MAX_PATH];
```

`memset()` won't allocate any memory for the buffer pointer.

---

Alternatively you could also use an initialized pointer:

```
char* buff = new[_MAX_PATH];
```

But don't forget to call

```
delete [] buff;
```

then, and that `sizeof()` won't give you the size of the allocated array but only the size of the pointer variable itself.

The even better alternative would be to use a `std::vector<char>` instead:

```
std::vector<char> buff(_MAX_PATH,'\0');
```

You need to change some more code to use that correctly though:

```
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buff.data(), _MAX_PATH);
char *file = strrchr(buff.data(), '.');
```

---

Also you should initialize your buffer with NUL chars rather than blanks (`' '`):

```
memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(buff));
           // ^^
```

Comment: "But don't forget to call

`delete [] buff;`" - or just use a `std::vector` or smart pointers and forget about having to do manual cleanup.

Comment: @Jesper Sure, that would be the better alternatives, but need more changes to the OPs code of course.

Comment: I just happen to believe that a good answer should mention better alternatives when they exist :) an answer is the perfect opportunity to educate.

Comment: @Jesper OK, I've added at least a mention for `std::vector`

Comment: No, I declared char buff[512];

Comment: @Patris Please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem in your question, before starting to argue in comments. If you declared your `buff` like stated you won't get that error message.

Comment: @Patris As mentioned [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44955559/edit) your question please.

Comment: So, what's the problem?@user0042

Comment: @Patris I cannot [**reproduce**](http://rextester.com/RSUD64729) what you're claiming in your question.

Comment: As I said, this is warning that _visual studio_ returns, not an error.@user0042

Comment: @Patris I noticed that and ticked _show compiler warnings_.

Comment: But _rextester_ isn't _visual studio_.@user0042

Comment: @Patris What makes you think it isn't? Of course the MSVC compiler is used. Visual Studio is just the IDE anyways.